# Change String color sent out using Outlook Email

Tags: java, email, html-email

I'm trying to change the color of a string that I'm sending out as part of the email using an email service, but I can't find any good resources on doing so. Here's the code that I have now:

```
String message = "hello world";
emailObject.setBody(message);
emailService.sendEmail(emailObject);
```

I want "hello world" to appear let's say, in red text, instead of the default black text. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: have you tried html markup?

Comment: Did you try to use HTML?

Comment: html doesn't work, it just outputs it with the html markup as literals

Comment: You will need tu change the content type. I updated my answer.

Comment: May you say what email API are you using?

Comment: im just sending it using java's SimpleMailMessage to set the content of the email and JavaMailSendImpl to send the actual email. I would rather use plain text if it is possible since I want to avoid changing the code for the email service portion, would that be possible?

Comment: Where is this class in JDK? Are you sure that is a native class?

Comment: its part of the springframework, i had to import it from org.springframework.mail, so I guess it's not a native class?

Comment: You said "Java's SimpleMailMessage", so I thought that was a native class... You will need to change to MimeMailMessage to use HTML.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion, I'm new to development and that portion of the code was done by someone else. Is there a way to change the color of the text of plain text?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22331/discussion-between-user974047-and-davidbuzatto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String message = "<span style=\"color: #FF0000\">hello world</span>";
```

You just need to use HTML markup in your text.

To make HTML work you will need to change the content type to "text/html", sayind to you email client that the content should be redered as HTML, not as plain text.

**Edit.**

You will need to use MimeMailMessage, MimeMessage and MimeMessageHelper to use HTML in your messages. Next time, try to explain more your problem, saying the API that you are using, showing more code, etc.

You can find some examples at the docs.

- [MimeMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html)
- [MimeMailMessage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMailMessage.html)
- [MimeMessageHealper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html)

Comment: Thank you David, this is a great learning experience for me in bettering myself on StackOverflow as well as a coder :)

Comment: @user974047: You are welcome ;) I updated my answer again, take a look. Let we know if your problem was solved and accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
String message = "<span style='color:red;'>hello world</span>";
```

Comment: If you put a blank line between "try..." and your code, you will get the fancy coloring for the code block.

Comment: @Windle The fancy coloring is called **syntax highlighting**. ;)

Comment: it doesn't work, the email will output the text as <span style='color:red;'>hello world</span>